# postgres, permute columns from file

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to permute the columns in `COPY table FROM 'file';` or should I use scripting for permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` takes an optional list of columns:

```
COPY tablename [ ( column [, ...] ) ]
    FROM { 'filename' | STDIN }
    ...
```

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-copy.html).